# C# WinForms ListBox changes selection to first item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I got a problem with a ListBox in a WinForm application. I have two ListBoxes inside of a tab control and depending on the selection in the first one (lb1), the DataSource of the second one (lb2) changes. This is done in the SelectedValueChanged Event.

```
        private void listBox_ControlUnits_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlUnit unit = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ControlUnit;

        textBox_ProjectNameTab.Text = unit.ProjectName;
        listBox_ControlCircuits.DataSource = null;
        listBox_ControlCircuits.DataSource = unit.ControlCircuits;           
    }
```

lb1 is filled with a DataSource, too.

Now if I select a value in lb1 the selection automatically jumps back to the first item and I can not figure out why. is this some kind of UI update problem?
Even without the SelectedValueChanged event and the connection to the second listbox the issue occures.

[Short gif of the problem, sorry for the blurriness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfZOH.gif)

If I select one item more than once it works somehow (as seen in the gif).

Edit:
I found the problem but I do not quite understand what happens.
I have another listBox on another tab of my tab control. This listBox has the same DataSource as lb1. This seems to cause this behavior.

Comment: Is there a SelectedValueChanged event on the listbox_ControlCircuit as well?

Comment: No event on this listBox.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem:
I did not know that if I use the same DataSource for two ListBoxes they share the BindingContext per default.
I created a new BindingContext for the second ListBox and now the selection does no longer change.

```
            listBox_allGroups.DataSource = null;
            listBox_allGroups.DataSource = x.y;
            listBox_allGroups.DisplayMember = "Name";

            listBox_ControlUnits.DataSource = null;
            listBox_ControlUnits.DataSource = x.y;
            listBox_ControlUnits.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox_ControlUnits.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to hold the selected item

```
object _selecteditem=null;
```

and check it in ListBox click event.

```
prive void ListBox1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
      if(ListBox1.SelectItem == _selecteditem) return;
      // do ...
}
```